# Is there a module cache in python?

Tags: python

When I do:

```
import os
os.system('pip install nose')
os.system('pip uninstall nose')
import nose
```

I get an error saying no nose, which is alright.

But when I do this:

```
import os
os.system('pip install nose')
import nose
del nose
os.system('pip uninstall nose')
import nose
```

it works! 
But when I go to the python packages directory, I cannot find nose. Is there some sort of cache for python modules?

Comment: You mean a cache for Python **modules**? Because yes, there is one. Python **variables** is a different thing.

Comment: When I run `os.system('pip uninstall nose')` as root, my system warns me `Not uninstalling nose at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS`.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan I used a venv